# Use regex to get number after the date from text file into LINQ group

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently reading a log file and need to get the value of filing number that proceeds the date/time and the regex matches the current phrase. My problem seems to be where I need to pass the datetime() value and filing number () in the same group. I know very little about regex and any assistance would be greatly appreciated. My application only looks back every 15 minutes in the log to see if that key wording has shown up as well which is why the `lastFailTime` is there.

Code:

```
string str = File.ReadAllText(file);

Regex regex = new Regex("(?<time>.+(AM|PM)).(?<after>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*There was no endpoint listening");

   var lastFailTime = File.ReadLines(file)
  .Select(line => regex.Match(line))
  .Where(m => m.Success) // take only matched lines
  .Select(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["time"].Value))
  .DefaultIfEmpty() // DateTime.Min if no failures
  .Max();
```

Comment: why not create a class that is the structure of the textfile then parse that file and assign the class fields to the appropriate values.. then you can get at the correct date values no matter what

Comment: @L.B. I have multiple regex for this project because a vendor not handling exceptions. I have been able to get the date/time and specific wording but my regex for the number following the datetime in not getting a value. Am I missing something in my regex structure?

Comment: Actually you get the number in "after" group. Strange that you're asking...

Comment: @mikalai that is my problem. I am unable to isolate the number after the datetime in the log file and I do not know how to get that value in the LINQ statement where I am already getting the time from the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
string result = Regex.Replace(searchText, "(?s)^(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+ [APM]{2}) (\\d+) (.*)$", "");
```

This regex returns the date and time in the first group, the ID in the second and everything else (the message) in the last.

The standard form of the above regex is

```
^(\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ [APM]{2}) (\d+) (.*)$
```

Comment: thank you for a valuable solution. Regex is the hardest thing I have come across in my programming experience. I'll try it today. `searchText` is going to be my variable for the specific word(s) I am looking for right?